# How to parse Retrofit JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, retrofit

I have a typical [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) API request:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(URL)
        .build();

ApiEndpointInterface api = restAdapter.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);

api.getToken('1', new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(DefaultResponse json, Response response) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError response) {
        //
    }
});
```

And the returned JSON is:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"token_id":"pPt9AKl0Cg","token_key":"8ax224sFrJZZkStAQuER"}}
```

How can I parse this JSON? It seems wrong/tedious to create a new model class for each different response across my app. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write your model class like below

```
public class MyResponseModel {//write setters and getters.
        private boolean success;
        private DataModel data;

    public static class DataModel {
        private String token_id;
        private String token_key;
    }
}
```

now  in your `getToken()` method should look like this

```
getToken('1', Callback<MyResponseModel> response);
```

`retrofit` will parse the response and convert it to the class above.

Comment: It seems wrong/tedious to create a new model class for each different response across my app, though. I have a dozen different JSON responses throughout my app. :/

Comment: ikr, that's why i always write a class that is called ResponseModel, which i add different variables to it, but tbh to keep things clean, you should have a model class for each response unless if they identically equal. its okay to have plenty of classes, what matters is the content inside and how complex it is. in this case model classes are just plain pojo classes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(s);
JsonObject asJsonObject = je.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement get = asJsonObject.get("data");
System.out.println(s + "\n" + get);
JsonObject asJsonObject1 = get.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement get1 = asJsonObject1.get("token_id");
System.out.println(get1);
JsonElement get2 = asJsonObject1.get("token_key");
System.out.println(get2);
```